# Missing partial invoices/__invoice_item_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have invoice and invoice_items models in my application. and i have used cocoon gem for nested models.i am using rails 4.2. it is working properly when i am creating new invoice, but when i am clicking on my edit button i am getting "template missing error" though i have _invoice_item_fields.html.erb file in my application.

this is my _form.html.erb file

```
<div class=" form">
  <%= form_for(@invoice,:html=>{:class=>"cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form",:novalidate=>"novalidat"}) do |f| %>
    <% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

      <div class="form-group ">
          <%= f.label :billing_address ,:class=>"control-label col-lg-2" %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.text_area :billing_address,:class=>"form-control"  %>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
          <%= f.label :shipping_address ,:class=>"control-label col-lg-2" %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.text_area :shipping_address,:class=>"form-control"  %>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
          <%= f.label :company_id ,:class=>"control-label col-lg-2" %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.number_field :company_id,:class=>"form-control"  %>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
          <%= f.label :invoice_date ,:class=>"control-label col-lg-2" %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.date_select :invoice_date,:class=>"form-control"  %>
        </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="form-group ">
          <%= f.label :status ,:class=>"control-label col-lg-2" %>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= f.number_field :status,:class=>"form-control"  %>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <section class="panel">
      <header class="panel-heading">
          Invoice Items
          <span class="pull-right">
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Item', f, :invoice_items,:class=>"btn btn-default"%>
        </span>  
      </header> 
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="adv-table">
          <%= f.fields_for :invoice_items do |item| %>
            <%= render '_invoice_item_fields', :f => item %>
          <% end %>
        </div>    
      </div>  
     </section> 
  </div>
</div>   


     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
          <%= f.submit "Save",:class=>"btn btn-danger"%>
        </div>  
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

this is my _invoice_item_fields.html.erb file

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
<%= render '_invoice_item_fields', :f => item %>
```

must be

```
<%= render 'invoice_item_fields', :f => item %>
```

You do not use a leading `_` in your Rails `render` call to render a partial. The underscore goes on the filename on disk only.